# Get IP from inventory which defined FQDN only

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

In the inventory file, I define FQDN values only. These domains point to the server IPs (used in DNS). I'd like to render the template file (Jinja) with the list of IPs. Do we have any solution?

Inventory file:

```ini
[example_instance]
example1.com
example2.com
```

Desired output of template file

```
address=10.10.10.10,10.10.10.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`dig`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/dig_lookup.html) lookup for that. But, mind that you also need the `dnspython` library installed on your controller for it to work.

So, given the two tasks:

```yaml
- pip:
    name: dnspython
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: yes

- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('dig', inventory_hostname) }}"
```

This would give you two IPs in return, in your case:

```yaml
ok: [example1.com] => 
  msg: 10.10.10.10
ok: [example2.com] => 
  msg: 10.10.10.11
```

---

In order to get a list of IPs from Ansible facts, given that you are targeting the group `example_instance` in your playbook, simply do, in your template:

```
address={{ hostvars
  | dict2items
  | selectattr('value.ansible_facts.default_ipv4', 'defined')
  | map(attribute='value.ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address')
  | join(',')
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder if we had any solution else. Like we use {{ansible_default_ipv4.address}} to get the ip of the current host. In this question, I'd like to get all ip addresses of the group.

Comment: @duyl97 you could too, but based on your specific architecture (if it includes reverse proxies, load balancers, ...) the DNS could resolve to another IP than the servers IP. In that sense, your question is a bit lacking context.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The hostnames should direct to server IPs. I'd like to render the config file with the list of IPs.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73441895/edit) your question, include this in and also add the desired output line of the template.